# AES decrypting files larger than available RAM

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, mbed

Up to this point, I used to decrypt files (located on an USB stick) with AES as follows:

```
FILE * fp = fopen(filePath, "r");
vector<char> encryptedChars;

if (fp == NULL) {
    //Could not open file
    continue;
}

while(true) {
    int nextEncryptedChar = fgetc(fp);

    if (nextEncryptedChar == EOF) {
        break;
    }

    encryptedChars.push_back(nextEncryptedChar);
 }

 fclose(fp);

 char encryptedFileArray[encryptedChars.size()];
 int encryptedByteCount = encryptedChars.size();

 for (int x = 0; x < aantalChars; x++) {
     encryptedFileArray[x] = encryptedChars[x];
 }

 encryptedChars.clear();

 AES aes;

 //Decrypt the message in-place
 aes.setup(key, AES::KEY_128, AES::MODE_CBC, iv);
 aes.decrypt(encryptedFileArray, sizeof(encryptedFileArray));
 aes.clear();
```

This works perfectly for small files. At this point, I am opening a file from a USB stick and storing all characters into a vector and copying the vector to an array. I know that &encryptedChars[0] can be used as an array pointer as well and will save some memory.

Now I want to decrypt a file of 256Kb (as opposed to 1Kb). Copying the data into a source array will require at least 256Kb of RAM. I however only have 100Kb at my disposal and therefore, cannot create a source array containing the encrypted data.

So I tried to use the FILE * that fopen gives me as a FILE pointer, and created a new file on the same USB stick as a destination pointer. I was hoping that the decryption rounds would use the memory of the USB stick as opposed to available memory on the heap.

```
FILE * fp = fopen(encryptedFilePath, "r");
FILE * fpDecrypt = fopen(decryptedFilePath, "w+");

if (fp == NULL || fpDecrypt == NULL) {
     //Could not open file!?
     return;
}

AES aes;

//Decrypt the message in-place
aes.setup(key, AES::KEY_128, AES::MODE_CBC, iv);
aes.decrypt((const char*)fp, fpDecrypt, firmwareSize); 
aes.clear();
```

Unfortunately, the system locks up (no idea why).

Does anybody know if I can pass a FILE * to a function that expects a const char * as source and a void * as a destination?

I am using the following library: https://os.mbed.com/users/neilt6/code/AES/docs/tip/AES_8h_source.html

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could decript your file in chunks, it is, while you read it.

Comment: The acronym "CBC" means "cyber block chain", with the key word there being "block". The entire thing can be decrypted one block at a time, using the appropriate APIs. The library you are using does not appear to support this kind of an API, so you will need to find a different encryption library.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It's "cipher", not "cyber".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of crypto libraries provide "incremental" APIs that allow a stream of data to be en/decrypted piece by piece, without having to load the stream into memory.  Unfortunately, it appears that [the library you're using](https://os.mbed.com/users/neilt6/code/AES/docs/09347d4bc827/classAES.html) doesn't (or, at least, does not explicitly document it).

However, if you know [how CBC mode encryption works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29), it's possible to roll your own.  Basically, all you need to do is take the last AES block (i.e. the last 16 bytes) of the previous chunk of ciphertext and use it as the IV when decrypting (or encrypting) the next block, something like this:

```
char buffer[1024];  // this needs to be a multiple of 16 bytes!
char ivTemp[16];
while(true) {
    int bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), inputFile);

    // save last 16 bytes of ciphertext as IV for next block
    if (bytesRead == sizeof(buffer)) memcpy(ivTemp, buffer + bytesRead - 16, 16);

    // decrypt the message in-place
    AES aes;
    aes.setup(key, AES::KEY_128, AES::MODE_CBC, iv);
    aes.decrypt(buffer, bytesRead);
    aes.clear();

    // write out decrypted data (todo: check for write errors!)
    fwrite(buffer, 1, bytesRead, outputFile);

    // use the saved last 16 bytes of ciphertext as IV for next block
    if (bytesRead == sizeof(buffer)) memcpy(iv, ivTemp, 16);

    if (bytesRead < sizeof(buffer)) break;  // end of file (or read error)
}
```

Note that this code will overwrite the `iv` array.  That should be OK, though, since you should never use the same IV twice anyway.  (In fact, with CBC mode, the IV should be chosen by the encryptor at random, using a cryptographically secure RNG, and sent alongside the message.  The usual way to do that is to simply prepend the IV to the message file.)

---

Also, the code above is somewhat less efficient than it needs to be, since it calls `aes.setup()` and thus re-runs the whole AES key expansion for each chunk.  Unfortunately, I couldn't find any *documented* way to tell your crypto library to change the IV without re-running the setup.

However, looking at the [implementation of your library](https://os.mbed.com/users/neilt6/code/AES/file/09347d4bc827/AES.cpp), as linked by [Sister Fister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8666346/sister-fister) in the comments below, it looks like it's already replacing its internal copy of the IV with the last ciphertext block.  Thus, it looks like all you *really* need to do is call `aes.decrypt()` for each block *without* a setup call in between, something like this:

```
char buffer[1024];  // this needs to be a multiple of 16 bytes!

AES aes;
aes.setup(key, AES::KEY_128, AES::MODE_CBC, iv);

while(true) {
    int bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), inputFile);

    // decrypt the chunk of data in-place (continuing from previous chunk)
    aes.decrypt(buffer, bytesRead);

    // write out decrypted data (todo: check for write errors!)
    fwrite(buffer, 1, bytesRead, outputFile);

    if (bytesRead < sizeof(buffer)) break;  // end of file (or read error)
}
aes.clear();
```

Note that this code is relying on a feature of the crypto library that does *not* seem to be explicitly documented, namely that calling `aes.decrypt()` multiple times will cause the decryptions to be chained correctly.  (That's actually a pretty reasonable thing to do, for CBC mode, but you can never be sure without reading the code or finding explicit documentation saying so.)  You should make sure to have a comprehensive test suite for this, and to re-run the tests whenever you upgrade the library.

Also note that I haven't tested either of these examples, so there obviously could be bugs or typos.  Also, the docs for your crypto library are somewhat sparse, so it's possible that it might not work exactly like I'm assuming it does.  Please test anything based on this code throughly before using it!

Comment: The [code](https://os.mbed.com/users/neilt6/code/AES/file/09347d4bc827/AES.cpp) in the library looks pretty simple, so it should be easy to just modify it to support piece by piece encryption. Replacing the `memcpy`s from the source buffer with your own callback or function would probaply be a simple solution.

Comment: @SisterFister: Thanks for that link! In fact, looking at the code, it seems that it's already replacing its internal copy of the IV with the last ciphertext block, so it should be sufficient to just repeatedly call `aes.decrypt()` without resetting the state in between. I've added an example of that above.

Comment: Looks like you're right, I got confused with the indentation levels and thought that the code is also doing some stuff outside of the `while` loop. So replacing the `memcpy`s should work, but it would actually be a bad solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I was able to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

In general, if something doesn't fit to memory, you can resort to:

1. Random accessing files. Use `fseek` to find the position and read or write what you need. Memory requirement minimal.
2. Processing in batches that will fit in to memory. Memory requirement is adjustable, but the algorithm must be suitable for this.
3. System virtual memory, which allows you to reserve as big blocks as your system can address, you have free disk space and your system settings. This is usually transparent depending on your system.
4. Other paged memory mechanisms.

Since AES encryption is made in blocks of 128 bits, and you're short of memory, you should probably use random  access on your file.